# How to store multivalued attributes of different tables in one table using their foreign key?

Tags: mysql, database

I have three tables: ***service_type_1, service_type_2, service_type_3***.

These tables have three common attributes: **id , name, image_path**.

I want to store more than one photo_path for a *service_type_1* table which makes image_path a multi-valued attribute. (The same applies to *service_type_2,service_type_3* tables.)

So, I created a separate table called *photo_details* for storing **image_path** for *service_type_1* table linking it through a foreign key attribute  **id**. Now the problem is I want to use *photo_details* table  to store **image_path** for both *service_type_2* and *service_type_3* also.

Is there any solution for this?

Should I create separate tables for *service_type_2,service_type_3* ?

Comment: no, add column `type` in `photo_details` table. where type = type_1,type_2,type_3

Answer (score 1):

Change the model if its posible to this:

```
 Table Types
  Type_id int
  Name    varchar

 Table Details_photo
  Id_detail  int
  Type_id    int      Foreign key references Type_id in table Types
  Name       varchar
  Image_path varchar
```

In this way you can use unlimited number of types and values...

Answer (score 0):

Add column `type` in `photo_details` table, it should look like:

```
photo_detail_id(PK)(int)  type_id(FK)(int)  type(enum)  image_path(varchar)
         1                      1              type_1        path
         2                      2              type_2        path
         3                      3              type_3        path
         4                      1              type_1        path
```